# Next.js GraphQL: Unable to fetch GraphQL API and getting "POST body missing, invalid Content-Type, or JSON object has no keys" error

Tags: next.js, graphql, apollo-server

I've created GraphQL API using Next.js API routes and Apollo Server Micro but I'm getting the following error accessing from apollo GraphQl explorer, postman, or curl command.

```
POST body missing, invalid Content-Type, or JSON object has no keys.
```

I made sure Content-Type: application/json was used, so I'm guessing something else is wrong.

Here are the packages (and versions) that I'm using in this project.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@apollo/client": "^3.7.15",
  "@types/node": "20.3.1",
  "@types/react": "18.2.12",
  "@types/react-dom": "18.2.5",
  "apollo-server-micro": "^3.12.0",
  "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
  "eslint": "8.42.0",
  "eslint-config-next": "13.4.5",
  "graphql": "^16.6.0",
  "micro": "^9.4.1",
  "next": "13.4.5",
  "postcss": "8.4.24",
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "18.2.0",
  "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
  "typescript": "5.1.3"
}
```

I've investigated what causes this error by simplifying my code as much as possible.
But I still don't get any hint to fix the error.

Here is the simple hello world schema and resolver.

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => 'Hello World',
  },
};
```

And my full code: src/pages/api/graphql.ts

```
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-micro';
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs, // defined above
  resolvers,  // defined above
});

const startServer = apolloServer.start();

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  /**** The error occurs either this part exists or not ****/
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
    'https://studio.apollographql.com'
  );
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  );
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.end();
    return false;
  }
  /*********************************************************/

  await startServer;
  await apolloServer.createHandler({
    path: '/api/graphql',
  })(req, res);
}
```

Can anyone tell how to fix the error, please?

**What did you try and what were you expecting?**

expecting to get response like below.

```
{
    "data": {
        "hello": "Hello World"
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably put the `await startServer; await apolloServer.createHandler()` outside of the `handler`

Comment: I created apolloHandler outside of the handler.
`const apolloHandler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => { await startServer; await apolloServer.createHandler({ path: '/api/graphql' })(req, res);};`
And replaced `await startServer; await apolloServer.createHandler()` with`apolloHandler`. But still not working.
Sorry if I misunderstood because I'm not sure how exactly put them outside of the handler.